# Spring MVC 4: Static content mapping is sometimes working sometimes not

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to solve this problem from last few hours.. but no luck.

I have below two methods:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String register(RegistrationForm registrationDetails){
    logger.info("Inside POST /register method");
    return "register";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showRegister(@RequestParam(value="name", required=true) String name, Model model){
    return "register";
}
```

As you can see I am trying to render same html page from both of these methods.

**Problem**: When I do GET, I see my web page perfectly fine. But when I do POST and return same html again, my css, js and images are not rendering at all. I don't know how the path to these files get messed up..

I tried to apply many many solutions which i found online. But no luck.
I get below errors:

```
WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/app/registers/resources/themes/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'
WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/app/registers/resources/themes/bootshop/bootstrap.min.css] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'
WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/app/registers/resources/themes/images/payment_methods.png] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'
```

html code where i reference these resources:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="resources/themes/images/ico/favicon.ico"></link>
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="resources/themes/images/ico/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png"></link>
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="resources/themes/images/ico/apple-touch-icon-114-precomposed.png"></link>
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="resources/themes/images/ico/apple-touch-icon-72-precomposed.png"></link>
```

Here is my servlet-context.xml

```
<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<annotation-driven />

<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources" />

<beans:bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine" />
    <beans:property name="order" value="1" />
    <beans:property name="viewNames" value="*.html,*.xhtml" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="templateResolver"
    class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".html" />
    <beans:property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine">
    <beans:property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine" />
</beans:bean>
```

My folder structure is:

[image: Directory structure]

I saw many people showing their directory structures in similar kind of problems, so i am showing it too.

Comment: Is `/app/registers/resources/themes/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css` the expected path to the resources? `/registers` doesn't seem to belong. Let's see your `<form>` or whatever you use to send a POST request.

Comment: Could you please post the code of your thymeleaf template, i expect that the probelm is with this file

Comment: Hey I solved this problem.. yes, you people are correct I was using <form action="register/" method="POST">. But when I removed "/", it worked.. Thanks.